# How to integrate testacular in a maven regular build with jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-maven-plugin

I just want to run a testacular unit test in a regular maven build.

I already have a jasmine build working on my project and I would like to integrate browser object from testacular to test the UI of my application.

Is it possible or do I must use nodejs to run test unit with testacular ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into calling `grunt` from the `exec-maven-plugin`? I run my karma e2e tests from maven by calling grunt directly from maven.